# NHibernate - CreateSqlQuery with same column name in two joined tables

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

As the subject stated, my problem is that when I write "select * from person left join animle on preson.animle_id = animle.ID"

Now, if both tables have "age" column for instance, I have a problem:

```
var query = "select * from person left join animle on preson.animle_id = animle.ID";

var List<Object[]> = createSqlQuery(query).addentity(person).addentity(animle).list<Object[]>();
```

The animle.age gets the person age value.

Is there a way that each object will recieve the correct values without changing the columns names ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning a unique alias to each `age` column in your original SQL query:

```
SELECT
    t1.age AS age_person,
    t2.age AS age_animal,
    ...    -- other columns
FROM person t1
LEFT JOIN animle t2
    ON t1.animle_id = t2.ID
```

I am not too familiar with C# or NHibernate, but you should be able to access `age_person` and `age_animal` as you would any other column.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, aliases for each column is a problem, the NH HBM files are already defined for a huge DB and these problematic columns are all over, I need NHibernate to be able to know what goes where...if possible of course

Comment: I think an alias is the only way to proceed here, otherwise you can't discriminate betweem the two columns.